# How to get process PID from PHP on Windows

Tags: php, windows, matlab, exec, pid

I am developing a web-based application and I need to run a Matlab script to process some information.

The problem is that I have a limitation on the maximum number of Matlab processes running at the same time and because of this, I have to get the PID of each process in order to know if any of them has crashed and which one it was.

I have used some methods to get its PID, but for some reason running a simple command like 'notepad.exe' works fine and gets the correct PID, but when I run my script it gets the wrong PID.

One of the methods I tried is this one:

```
$process = "matlab";
$command = "-sd ".$softExecPath." -r \"analyse('".$videoDataPath."', '".$id_video_data."') \" ";
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->exec($process." ".$command);
$pid = intval($oExec->ProcessID);
```

And the other one is:

```
$process = "matlab";
$command = "-sd ".$softExecPath." -r \"analyse('".$videoDataPath."', '".$id_video_data."') \" ";
$command = $process." ".$command;
// use psexec to start in background, pipe stderr to stdout to capture pid
exec("C:/AppServ/www/PsTools/psexec.exe -d -accepteula $command 2>&1", $output);
// capture pid on the 6th line
preg_match('/ID (\d+)/', $output[5], $matches);
$pid = $matches[1];
```

Both of them get a PID but none of them is the real one.

Comment: Is this Perl? I thought `exec()` never returned when successful. In the second example, what's the return value of `exec()` and the contents of $! after the call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, the Matlab program that you call to launch Matlab (the one pointed to by the shortcut in the Start Menu and on the path if you added it) is just a launcher program that goes on to run another `matlab.exe` which is the actual program, and then returns immediately. The PID you're getting back is that of the launcher program, which'll be gone by the time the real Matlab is doing work.

Two things you can do: You can run the actual `matlab.exe` program directly by finding it in the bin/win32 or similar platform-specific directory under the Matlab installation. Then you'll get the right PID back. Or you can fiddle with the `-wait` option to make the launcher program run synchronously, which means it'll block until the child `matlab.exe` exits, so it'll still show up in the process list while Matlab is running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've been trying running Matlab directly from bin/win64/MATLAB.exe and I finally get the correct PID.

The problem is -which didn't happen before- that once the process has been created my Matlab script -that should create an XML with some data- does nothing and never stops running.

Comment: Can you see the Matlab GUI pop up and start running when you run it interactively? Does it look like it's getting through startup and attempting to call analyze()? Could be the launcher program is needed for some of the `-sd` and `-r` support, though IIRC it's not. What happens if you try the `-wait` option on the normal launcher program instead?

Comment: Running manually the command from the bin/win64 folder gives me an exception. Matlab console says that there is no 'analyse' function with 'char' arguments, so it seems that there is some problem with my command, although I can't see what it is: 

`exec(" \"C:/Program Files/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/win64/MATLAB.exe\" -sd C:/AppServ/www/videos_file_system/Soft/V1 -r \"analyse('C:/AppServ/www/videos_file_system/Data/- 176CJF (IBS SB2) 28 Apr 10/V1', '42') \" ")`

Comment: Looks like your analyse.m file is not getting on the Matlab path when it runs. Could be it's not respecting the -sd option. Is analyse.m directly in the Soft/V1 folder? Try cding to that directory before calling exec(), or do an addpath() inside the -r instead of using -sd. E.g. `-r \"addpath('C:/AppServ/www/videos_file_system/Soft/V1'); analyse('C:/AppServ/www/videos_file_system/Data/- 176CJF (IBS SB2) 28 Apr 10/V1''); quit() \"`.